# How to pass a react native component to a native module for Android

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a native module for android react native, written in java. How can you pass a component to the native module, like for example I have a custom made dialog using `MaterialStyledDialogs`([link](https://github.com/javiersantos/MaterialStyledDialogs)) and I want to set a [custom view](https://github.com/javiersantos/MaterialStyledDialogs/wiki/Adding-a-custom-view) for it, and that view is a react native component. Is this possible?

I can pass a string without a problem, but not with a component. For example

I have a component called `<CustomListForDialog/>` and then I'm gonna pass this to the native module via the  like so

```
...
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
...
// the custom function inside the class
showCustomDIalog() {
  NativeModules.MyNativeDialog.show('Header Title', <CustomListForDialog/>);
}
...
```

How to receive the component from the native module? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send or receive components in `react-native`. React Native Native modules can get only the following data types as Arguments.

```
Boolean -> Bool
Integer -> Number
Double -> Number
Float -> Number
String -> String
ReadableMap -> Object
ReadableArray -> Array
```

Read more about [ReadableMap](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableMap.java) and [ReadableArray](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableArray.java)

Comment: any works around to achieve my goal then? Maybe there is a different approach for it. Just like the Modal that contains a View component.

Comment: Just send the data to the Native code, process it there. Get back the processed data. Then, Generate the component. This is the only way.

Comment: @KennethPalaganas try to look at the implementation of measureLayout method, it is a native module which uses native component to compute result and send in callback.